# Как компактно распарсить несколько url, для дальнейшего вывода Name и Image в строку TableView?

Tags: swift

Как сделать это компактно?

Есть массив: itemArr =[StructData]

URL1 http://mainsite.ru/blabla.json содержащий:

> [       {         "id": 1,        "name": "Tanya",    },    {         "id": 2,        "name": 
>   "Sasha",  }]

URL2 http://somesite.ru/X.json (где X - это id из первого урла. 
Например для name: Tanya получим:

> ```
> [{ "id": 1,"imageID": "23"}]
> ```

URL3 http://somePictures.ru/Y.jpeg - где Y это imageID

Мне нужно вывести в строку в TableView: Name и Image (использую SD_Image для картинок и SwiftyJSON для парсинга).

Допустим, формат парсинга для URL1 такой:

```
    func parseJSON(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://mainsite.ru/blabla.json")

    guard let downloadURL = url else {return}

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, response, error in
               guard let data = data else {return}
                do{
                    let myJSON = try JSON(data: data)

                    for item in myJSON.arrayValue {

                       let id = item["id"].intValue
                       let name = item["name"].stringValue
                     self.itemsArr.append(StructData(id: id, name:name)
                  }

            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389407/how-do-i-optimize-chaining-async-requests-in-swift

Comment: А как распарсить оба url так чтобы в массив записались "name" из URL1 и "imageID" из URL2? Есть примеры кода?